# Waiting for a response in a thread

Tags: android

I want to recycle my image , but since another thread is rendering them, I need to be sure that the rendering has stopped:

```
     private void unload() {
        System.out.println("Unloading menu...");
        loaded = false;
        while(rendering) {
            //wait
        }
        background.recycle();  
        button.recycle();
        button_pushed.recycle();
     }
```

But I dont think this is the best way , are their other ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use thread wait()/notify() mechanism. you will find lots of nice tuts on the web